# Find max difference in array element

Tags: arrays, algorithm, function, max, min

Sample case:
`a[]={1,4,2,5,10,5,4}; //output== 9`
here we cannot change the order of element smaller always appear before bigger element 
The constraint are:

```
1<=n<=10^4
10^-6<=a[i]<=10^-6
```

Here is my code but it will fail on some test cases ,can someone find the error in this code.
Thank You .

```
int maxDiff(int *a,int n)
{
   int MIN_value=INT_MAX;
   int MAX_vale=INT_MIN;
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        MIN_value=min(MIN_value,a[i]);
        MAX_value=max(a[i]-MIN_value,MAX_value);
    }
 return MAX_value;

}
```

Comment: Output should be 9, `10-1 = 9`.

Answer (score 1):

The error must be in the logic of this line:

```
MAX_value=max(a[i]-MIN_value,MAX_value);
```

Use a debugger to test the method on different inputs and trace if `MAX_Value` gets the values assigned you expect it to get.

You may just set `MAX_value` correctly and return the difference afterwards:

```
MAX_value=max(MAX_value,a[i]);
```

Finally:

```
return MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE;
```

Be aware that if the difference is negative then the array was empty.

Edit: Compute the difference between the maximal value and the minimal value to the *left* of the maximal value (see comments):

```
possibleMinValue = min(possibleMinValue,a[i]);

oldMaxValue = MAX_value;
MAX_value=max(MAX_value,a[i]);

if (oldMaxValue != MAX_value) {
    // Found a new maximal value. Thus, possibleMinValue is a valid min value
    MIN_value = possibleMinValue;
}
```

Comment: here a[i]<a[j]  && i<j when we find the max diff suppose a sample case 2 5 7 1 the output should be 5 (7-2) not 6(7-1)

Comment: Am I right that you search for a difference where the MIN-element **must** be to the *left* of the MAX-element in all cases? Then you should hold two MIN-values. One is called `possibleMinValue` and the other `minValue`. Replace your current MIN-logic with `possibleMinValue` and assign `possibleMinValue` to `minValue` each time MAX-value changes.

Comment: That would be the best way to go about it. Simply do two for loops. In the first, find the `MAX_VALUE` and its position in the array, in the second, find a `MIN_VALUE` to the left of the `maxPos`.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj the time complexity also matter if you are going to take two loop definitely it will give TLE .

Comment: @DevendraPratapSingh Have you tried it? The maximum would be `2 x 10^4` which definitely would **NOT** give a time error.

Comment: If you use my approach (use two values) you will not need two loops... Just do as I told in the last comment of mine. Every time a new MAX-value occurs, the last seen Min-value will be valid again. Thus you take it into `minValue`. So at each time `possibleMinValue` holds the true Min-value of the whole array up to the current position and `minValue` holds the valid difference you search.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is wrong because, if it finds the minimum value at the end of the array, all your previous calculations of differences are invalidated. Your error is thus in the line:

```
MAX_value=max(a[i]-MIN_value,MAX_value);
```

A much better way to go about this would be:

```
int maxDiff(int *a,int n)
{
   if (n == 0 || n == 1)    //If list is empty or has 1 element, return 0
       return 0;
   int MIN_value=INT_MAX;
   int MAX_vale=INT_MIN;
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        MIN_value=min(MIN_value,a[i]);
        MAX_value=max(a[i],MAX_value);
    }
 return MAX_value - MIN_VALUE;

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of my answer but +1 for full code example.

Answer (score 0):

When finding the min or max of an array it is best to set the initial max or min to the first possible outcome; in this case it would be number 1 - number 2. This is to ensure that INT_MAX and INT_MIN do not become your final answer. Alternatively, when finding the min you can use INT_MAX as the initial value for your min or vice versa.

```
int findMaxDiff(int* array, int n) {
    int max = array[i];
    int min = array[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         if(array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i]
         }
         if(array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i]
         }
    }
    return max - min;
}
```